# Communicating GCM service and updating application data in realtime with meteor in mobile app

Tags: javascript, android, meteor

I am new learner of meteorJS, as to learn meteor,I started developing chat application in it,I done with a simple chat application with meteor application which inserts message in database and the messages section will just update all messages available in database. Now the problem is with mobile clients. How do I connect mobile applications with meteor when these mobile applications are closed. This means, I just want to push messages to android applications using gcm service and android application updates data when gcm sends update notification. And application will show notifications also. Can I create android application using meteorjs?how?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you can create android apps from meteor app using [Cordova](https://cordova.apache.org/), [this](https://github.com/meteor/meteor/wiki/Meteor-Cordova-Phonegap-integration) is a documentation about Meteor cordova integration which explains how to create meteor apps for Android and iOs, For the gcm push messages you can use meteor packages like [raix:push](https://atmospherejs.com/raix/push).